# perl with mysql, terribly slow, how to fix it

Tags: mysql, perl, performance

I have a very tiny perl script which extract one column from original table to form a new table, and generate the relation table by the way

```
$sqr->$conn->prepare("select id, authors from paper");
$sqr->execute();
while(@row = $sqr->fetchrow_array()) {
  paper_id = $row[0];
  @author_arr = someExtractFunc($row[1]);
  for (@author_arr) {
    author_id = insertAuthor($_);
    insertAuthorPaper(author_id, paper_id); # this is the relation_table between author and paper
  }
}
```

I have 80,000papers, about 240,000 authors, and this script runs terribly slow, can any one tell me why and give me some advice?

```
paper
id authors title

author
id name

author_paper
id author_id paper_id
```

Comment: have you tried batch inserting?

Comment: Do you have any indexes? It's almost impossible to diagnose database problems without seeing the schema.

Answer (score 4):

This can probably be solved entirely in MySQL by running query like

```
INSERT INTO
  newTable(field1,field2,...)
SELECT 
   field1, field2
FROM
   oldTable;
```

Comment: the ans is not what i wanted.I want to

Comment: Thank you very much.But the ans is not what I wanted. I've cleared the question.